# Can I enter the UK if my visa is expiring within 2 weeks?

Tags: visas, uk

I am on a tier2 dependent visa which is expiring in 3 weeks. I would like to enter the UK 2 weeks prior to the visa expiry date. Do I need to have entry clearance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can enter. You must leave on or before the expiry date.

Comment: Traveller, can you please add a link and/or quote with the information to this answer? While I am sure it is right, people who do not know your reputation may not.